# Initialising a mysql database and persist data using Docker compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a web application that uses two docker containers: one contains the application code and the other container is a mysql database instance.

I am trying to populate the db with an sql file and also try to persist the database data through a volume. I am encountering an issue with the sql init file being copied into the mysql container but not being executed.

This is how my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.19
        command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/mysql 
            - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro 
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
        networks: 
            - backend

    app:
        build: app
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - 5000:5000
        networks: 
            - backend
            - frontend
        volumes:
            - ./app/src:/code

volumes:
    db-data:
networks: 
    backend:
    frontend:
```

And this is the log when starting the mysql container

```
2021-04-17 12:34:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.

2021-04-17 12:34:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2021-04-17 12:34:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.

2021-04-17T12:34:01.466444Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.

2021-04-17T12:34:01.466615Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1

2021-04-17T12:34:01.891144Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

2021-04-17T12:34:01.895163Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.

2021-04-17T12:34:01.916128Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19' socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' port: 3306 MySQL Community Server - GPL.

2021-04-17T12:34:02.051164Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

It does not look like the init.sql file is being executed. Also from the mysql container CLI I can see that the 'init.sql' file has been copied.

```
# cd docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
# ls
init.sql
# mysql -u root -p

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| example            |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I am quite new to Docker and Docker compose but I cannot figure out how to make this work.

Comment: Is this the very first time you've run this Compose setup?  If you ran `docker-compose up`, then added the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` mount, then ran `docker-compose up` again, the initialization scripts won't run (since there is existing database content in the volume).

Comment: I have run it multiple times. I am using ```docker compose down -v``` before rebuilding and upping.